# How to make a div with overflow y scroll responsive (height wise)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Desired result is

1. The divs inside second div should always have `overflow-y scroll`.
2. The button at the bottom should always stick to bottom of window
3. This structure should be responsive should stay like this even on resize.

I am open to use bootstrap or something that solves this issue

```css
 .border {
      border: 1px solid
    }
```

```html
<div class="border" style="height: 79px;">

</div>

<div class="border" style="height: 716px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-top: 20px">

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>


</div>

<button style="width: 100%">This button should stick to bottom</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May you have to get the all space inside window with additional div as container ads stick it to edges with (top/left/right/height = 0px)!

Even may you need make container `overfolow:none` for future use!

The height of scrollable div calculated with CSS function "calc" as follow:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 124px);
  /*124px => 10px on container margin + 79px top div + 15px button + 20 px this top margin*/
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>

    <div class="border scrollable">
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;"></div>
    </div>

    <button style="width: 100%;">This button should stick to bottom</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: So this is only way for responsive heights ? do you know if there is any bootstrap class ?

Comment: Yes that's it.
No I dont know, I always use this way to implement my web apps, My JS that require MooTools and my CSS...

Comment: I see, I found out best to use height in `vh`it works like percentage

Comment: Remember that vh= Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*
So, It will be a float in result and may be not what you looking for!

But calc give you absolutely what you want! However I dont know Browser compatibility about it.

Answer (score 1):

I used the Position:sticky

and i added a flex box flex columns to make sure that it is more responsive

you may want to check https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky to make sure it works for your purpose

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>
  .container{
  
  }
    .border {
      border: 1px solid
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .sticky-bottom {
      width: 100%;
      position:sticky;
      bottom:0;
      z-index:900;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">

  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="border" style="height: 716px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-top: 20px">

      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>

      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>

      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>

      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>

      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>
      <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="sticky-bottom">This button should stick to bottom</button>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean by those requirements but to make the button sticky, you can use the sticky position. See example. Also for your fixed height, for which element? The individual divs or the second div?

A great read for Sticky would be:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <style>
    .border {
      border: 1px solid
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="border" style="height: 79px;">

</div>

<div class="border" style="overflow-y: scroll; margin-top: 20px">

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>

  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>
  <div class="border" style="height: 79px;">
  </div>


</div>

<button style="width: 100%; position: sticky; bottom: 0">This button should stick to bottom</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good answer but, the inner div scroll doesn't work now, edited question